# Synthetic kernel debugging for Hyper-V virtual machines not working - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: kernel, windbg, hyper-v

I want to kernel-debug my Hyper-V VMs. I can do it via COM port to pipe method ([Ref](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2011/12/30/configuring-a-hyper-v-vm-for-kernel-debugging/)), but that gives me throughput of 60-80 KBytes/sec, which is too slow for e.g. take dump files.

So, I'm trying to setup [Synthetic kernel debugging for Hyper-V virtual machines](http://withinrafael.com/how-to-set-up-synthetic-kernel-debugging-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines), but Kernel debugger never connects.

Troubleshooting and details:

- I verified that the the worker process `vmwp.exe` listens to UDP:55555 by running `netstat -nao | findstr /C:"55555"`.
- I tried to connect from another machine, and confirmed via wireshark that windbg on the other machine indeed sends packets to UDP:55555
- I've created a Windows Firewall rule allowing UDP:55555 from all IPs, bound to all profiles.
- My host and Guest OSs are Windows 10 v1703 64-bit.

Comment: Is synthetic debugging really different from [debugging via Ethernet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection)?

Comment: I did manage to debug a physical machine via Ethernet. However I believe you can't do that in a VM - as explained in the guide, synthetic debugging means the signal goes: VM == VMBUS == host VMBUS == Host TCP/IP == Debugger