# Connecting kernel debugger to Azure VM

Tags: kernel, windbg

I want to connect a kernel debugger to my Azure-hosted Windows VM. Obviously I can't do it via Serial, IEEE1394 or USB. I've had good luck kernel-debugging local machines via network [(ref)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection) - is this expected to work on Azure VMs as well?

Answer (score 2):

I am in the process and have partial success. Let me share it might be you will have better luck. Mine is a Single Node Azure stack, please note this is Azure Stack and not Azure.
Open a command prompt in Hyper-V window and do
bcdedit /debug on
bcdedit /dbgsettings NET HOSTIP: PORT:50002 Key:1.2.3.4
or
bcdedit /dbgsettings NET HOSTIP: PORT:50002 Key:1.2.3.4   busparams:Bus:Dev:Func
Go to Device Manager --> Network and locate the Ethernet card you are connected to and give its PCIe address Bus:Dev:Func
For me the first one did not work but with busparams it did work. I could break in. First make sure you can ping the host and target.

Problems: Either setting "bcdedit /debug on" or using of the the ethernet port for debug prevents the portal from working. So I hooked up another port it did not work. I Googled and got the impression that this might be a single node Azure Stack Deployment issue only. On a multinode it appears it might work. Now for hooking the VM my guess is the same procedure might work. I have not tried yet.

I read some where USB/COM port based WinDbg working chances are more.

Comment: Thanks. This sound more like Synthetic kernel debugging, which I tried before (my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44779655). However, I wanted an actual Azure machine, where I don't control the host.

Either way, I already managed via local KD + dump using `livekd -ml`.

Comment: A colleague reported that I should be able to use regular [Ethernet Kernel Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection) on Hyper-V machines, including on Azure-hosted VMs.

Comment: Epilogue: Ethernet Kernel Debugger works great for me.